Pydantic custom settings source running before default ones
I must load data into my Pydantic model with 3 different ways (env variables, .env file and Google Secret Manager).
Why ?
Locally -> env vars + .env file
GCP -> env vars + secret manager
So, I created this class
class Settings(BaseSettings):
    """Settings class."""

    VAR1: str
    VAR2: str
    VAR3: str

    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(case_sensitive=True, extra="ignore", env_file=".env", env_file_encoding="utf-8")

    @classmethod
    def settings_customise_sources(
        cls,
        settings_cls: type[BaseSettings],
        init_settings: InitSettingsSource,
        env_settings: EnvSettingsSource,
        dotenv_settings: DotEnvSettingsSource,
        file_secret_settings: PydanticBaseSettingsSource,
    ) -> tuple[PydanticBaseSettingsSource, ...]:
        return (
            init_settings,
            env_settings,
            dotenv_settings,
            GoogleSecretManagerSettingsSource(settings_cls),
        )

But for example if VAR1 is not in the env_settings but in the init_settings (Settings(VAR1="foo")) or in my .env file (dotenv_settings), Pydantic will first this to access the value in Google Secret Manager although I put GoogleSecretManagerSettingsSource last.
Any idea on how to solve this ?
(GoogleSecretManagerSettingsSource is based on this)

Maybe GCP is overriding the config? You are pulling variable fart from dotenv but GCP also have a fart variable. I dont know how exactly your inner functions work but huge possibility GCP is overriding it.
